# What are these trackers that I found in application autostart?

Tags: debian

Is this a virus?
Or could it be related to the ethereum (crypto currency) client I have installed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not a virus, it is a dependency of `ethereum` package.

See the output of:

```
apt-cache depends --recurse  ethereum |grep tracker
```